# Capturar dados seguindo padrão até último espaço

Tags: php, regex

Estou tentando fazer um scrapping de um site, e gostaria de capturar o valor que segue o padrão abaixo:

```
Advogado: XXXXX Número do Processo: XXXXXX OutroCampo: XXXXX
```

geralmente o que separa essas informações é um espaço, então seria o que seria capturado é, por exemplo, Advogado: `Bill Gates`(aqui teria um espaço/tab)

Padrão:

NOME_DO_CAMPO:(espaço opcional)`Valor a ser capturado`(espaço final)

Comecei com esse regex, mas ele só captura o início e não o valor "entre"

regex: `\w+:\s{1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se é disso que precisa:

```
<?php

$string = 'Advogado: XXX XX Número do Processo: XX XXXX OutroCampo: XXX XX';

preg_match_all('/(Advogado\:)(.+?)(Número\sdo\sProcesso\:)(.+?)(OutroCampo\:)(.+?)$/', $string, $matches);


echo 'MATCHES: <br>';
echo 'Advogado: '.$matches[2][0].'<br>';
echo 'Processo: '.$matches[4][0].'<br>';
echo 'Outro campo: '.$matches[6][0].'<br>';

echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
```

> Saída:

```
MATCHES: 
Advogado: XXX XX 
Processo: XX XXXX 
Outro campo: XXX XX
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Advogado: XXX XX Número do Processo: XX XXXX OutroCampo: XXX XX
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Advogado:
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  XXX XX 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Número do Processo:
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  XX XXXX 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => OutroCampo:
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  XXX XX
        )

)
```

[Exemplo no RegEx101.com](https://regex101.com/r/unsBPL/1)

Answer (score 2):

Ter espaços como o delimitador de campos, e permitir espaços nos valores do campo pode se tornar um problema. É improvável, mas se o nome do advogado for "Número do Processo: XXXXXX OutroCampo: XXXXX" fica difícil de validar.

De qualquer forma imagino que o que você queira seja um simples `'/^Advogado:\s?(.*)\s?Número do Processo/'`. Não há porque validar uma sequencia de letras com `\w+` já que a primeira palavra sempre será Advogado.

Exemplo:

```
$entrada = "Advogado: Bill Gates Número do Processo: XXXXXX OutroCampo: XXXXX";
preg_match('/^Advogado:\s?(.*)\s?Número do Processo/', $entrada, $match);

//toda a expressão 'Advogado: Bill Gates Número do Processo'
echo $match[0];

echo '<br>';

//apenas o match entre parenteses 'Bill Gates'
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: É porque o campo (Advogado) pode variar, ai usei o \w+

Comment: e o "número do processo" também

Comment: Se os dados podem variar, sugiro que edite a pergunta e coloque mais alguns casos. Mas já adianto que, se tanto o valor do campo (nome e sobrenomes) quanto o que vem depois ("Número do processo") estão separados por espaços, fica meio difícil saber onde termina um e começa outro